# Leetcode 297 Serialize and Deserialize Binary Tree

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

so I am doing leetcode 297. For some reason my TreeNode pointer for my deserialize helper function will not pass by reference. I know people say how stupid I am since pointers are passed by reference automically. However, I just couldn't figure out why it will not pass by reference in this case. Maybe that's not the problem. Please help me. Here is my code:

```
class Codec {
public:

// Encodes a tree to a single string.
string serialize(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<char> solution;

    serializeHelper( solution, root );

    string result( solution.begin( ), solution.end( ) );

    //cout << result << endl;

    return result; 
}

// Decodes your encoded data to tree.
TreeNode* deserialize(string data) {
    TreeNode* currentPtr; 
    TreeNode* root = currentPtr; 
    int index;

    if( data == "" )
        return NULL; 


    deserializeHelper( data, currentPtr, 1 );

    //cout << root->left->val;

    return root; 
}

private:

void deserializeHelper( string data, TreeNode* currentPtr, int index )
{
    if( index <= data.length( ) )
    {
        if( data[index - 1] != '$' )
        {
            currentPtr = new TreeNode( data[index - 1] - '0' );
            deserializeHelper( data, currentPtr->left, ( 2 * index ) );
            deserializeHelper( data, currentPtr->right, ( 2 * index ) + 1 );
            cout << currentPtr->left << " ";
        }
    }

}

void serializeHelper( vector<char>& solution, TreeNode* currentPtr )
{
    queue<TreeNode*> myQueue; 

    myQueue.push( currentPtr );
    while( !myQueue.empty( ) )
    {
        currentPtr = myQueue.front( ); 

        if( currentPtr != NULL )
        {
            myQueue.push( currentPtr->left );
            myQueue.push( currentPtr->right );
            solution.push_back( currentPtr->val + '0' );
        }

        if( currentPtr == NULL )
            solution.push_back( '$' ); 

        myQueue.pop( );
    }
}
};
```

Comment: You should pass the `std::string` as `const` reference.  This avoids the need to copy the entire structure.

Comment: No, pointers are not passed by reference automatically and I'm not sure why you would think so. If you don't explicitly use `&`, you will get a copy.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
void deserializeHelper( string data, TreeNode* currentPtr, int index )
```

`currentPtr` is updated with a new address. `currentPtr` is a pointer. It is a variable that contains the address of another variable. The other variable is passed by into `deserialzeHelper` by reference because `currentPtr` is a pointer. The same cannot be said for `currentPtr` itself.

`currentPtr` is a new variable that contains a copy of the address stored by the pointer used in the function call just like `data` is a new variable that's a copy of the first parameter and `index` is a copy of the last.

Since you wish to update `currentPtr`, you need a reference to the source pointer itself.

```
void deserializeHelper( string data, TreeNode* & currentPtr, int index )
```

Where we're here, there may be advantages to

```
void deserializeHelper( const string & data, TreeNode* currentPtr, int index )
```

to prevent copies of `data`. Sometimes a compiler will do this for you, but I'm not willing to risk it across the all compilers and especially not in a recursive function where you could be making hundreds of copies.

Comment: Thank you so much.